# Underline coordinates when they are within 20px of the center

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a div acting like a canvas that shows the coordinates of where the mouse is on that canvas. I am trying to get the coordinates to be underlined when they are within 20px of the center but I am not sure how to approach it as I am new to VueJS.

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas" v-bind:class="canvasClasses"  @mousemove="getCoordinates">
    {{coordinates.x}},{{coordinates.y}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = new Vue ({
    el: '#canvas',
    data: {
        canvasClasses: ["canvas", "font"],
        underlineClass: ["underlineFont"],
        coordinates: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        } 
    },
    methods: {
        getCoordinates(ml){
            this.coordinates.x = ml.offsetX;
            this.coordinates.y = ml.offsetY;
        }
    }
})
```

CSS:

```
.canvas{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #74b9ff;
}

.font{
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.underlineFont{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class binding for the coords that returns the value of `underlineClass` if the radius requirements are met:

```html
<span :class="coordsClass">{{coordinates.x}},{{coordinates.y}}</span>
```

The computed checks whether the current `x` and `y` are within the bounds of the radius and, if so, returns the class name (else no class name is returned):

```js
computed: {
  coordsClass() {
    const x = this.coordinates.x;
    const y = this.coordinates.y;
    const xO = this.origin.x;
    const yO = this.origin.y;
    if ( x >= xO - this.radius && x <= xO + this.radius
      && y >= yO - this.radius && y <= yO + this.radius ) {
      return this.underlineClass; 
    }
  }
```

Use a `radius` and an `origin` declared in `data`:

```
data() {
  return {
    ... // Other data
    origin: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    radius: 20 // Size of radius in pixels
  }
}
```

Calculate the `origin` when the component is mounted:

```js
mounted() {
  this.origin.x = this.$el.clientWidth / 2;
  this.origin.y = this.$el.clientHeight / 2;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/2d1zphcj/)

Comment: Thanks, this was actually super helpful. Especially the demo, I was able to mess around with a lot of things and see how this was working. The only things I did not quite understand was why <span :class="coordsClass"> doesnt have anything before the ":class" part. Does writing it like that just default to v-bind?

Comment: Nice, you're welcome.  Yes, `:` is just shorthand for `v-bind:`.  Similarly, `@` is shorthand for `v-on:`